# overlap two JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to overlap (merge-ish) two JSON object into one, where the new one would have all distinct values + ONLY one copy of the repeated ones ?

Example:

```
obj1 = Po {NAME: "12", START: 1, MAX: 10}
Po {NAME: "12", START: 4, MAX: 0}
Po {NAME: "12", START: 5, MAX: 20}

obj2 = Po {NAME: "12", START: 2, MAX: 0}
Po {NAME: "12", START: 4, MAX: 100}

Result = Po {NAME: "12", START: 1, MAX: 10}
Po {NAME: "12", START: 2, MAX: 0}
**Po {NAME: "12", START: 4, MAX: 100}**
Po {NAME: "12", START: 5, MAX: 20}
```

PS. the position 4 is duplicated in this example. whenever it's duplicated, I'd like to use the obj2 values (MAX) instead of obj1.

I tried to use $.extend and merge but I always come up with duplicated entries for the same position :/

Any insight/help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the exact syntax for $.extend() you used

Comment: I am not sure what do "Po" means is both object an array?

Comment: var t_ = $.extend(obj1,obj2 )
$.unique(t_) **** tried this but doesn't work for me 
t_.sort(function(a,b) {return d3.ascending(a.START, b.START)})

Comment: With you extend code it looks like a array .